# How to apply fundamental theorem of calculus for double integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

Find $$F''(\pi)$$

if $$F(x)=\int_{x}^{\sin(x)} \left(\int_0^{\sin(t)}\sqrt{1+u^4}\text{d}u\right)\text{d}t$$

I'm not even sure where to begin... I'm thinking of splitting the function into 
$$F(x)=\int_{0}^{\sin(x)}\left(\int_0^{\sin(t)}\sqrt{1+u^4}\text{d}u\right)\text{d}t-\int_0^x \left(\int_0^{\sin(t)}\sqrt{1+u^4}\text{d}u\right)\text{d}t$$

and now i'm stuck @.@

i know I'm suppose to use the Fundamental theorem of calculus but how do i apply it to double integrals?

Ok so what i've got so far is

$$F'(x)=\int_{0}^{\sin(\sin(x))}\cos(x)\sqrt{1+u^4}\text{d}u-\int_0^{\sin(x)}\sqrt{1+u^4}\text{d}u$$

and how i'm stuck with the first part @.@

Comment: It's really an iterated integral rather than a double integral, so you do it one integral at a time.

Comment: @MichaelHardy ok. im trying. am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Your first step is good. Then you need to say $\displaystyle\frac d{dx}\int_0^{\sin x}h(t)\,dt= h(\sin x)\cdot\frac d{dx}\sin x$, etc. That gives your inside integral as $\displaystyle\int_0^{\sin\sin x}\cdots\cdots\,du$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I got the answer for F''(pi) as 2. is that right?

Answer (score 2):

Define
$$
g(t)=\int_{0}^{\sin t}\sqrt{1+u^4}\,du.
$$
Then
$$
F(x)=\int_0^{\sin x}g(t)\,dt-\int_0^x g(t)\,dt.
$$
Now use the Fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule.

Comment: Hmm ok let me try that

Comment: Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Fine up to now. Use again the FTC, the chain rule AND the product rule (take $\cos x$ out of the first integral).